# Will Guava cache retry cache load with another thread when cache load fails?

Tags: guava

If I got it right, threads that call get(key) will be blocked until first thread finishes cache load. But what will happen if it fails to load cache? (exception thrown for example). Will another thread that call get(key) retry cache load?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all calls to the loading cache either fetch the stored value or try to block and fetch the value from the downstream source from a `CacheLoader`.

From [the Wiki page](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained#from-a-cacheloader) (emphasis mine):

> A `LoadingCache` is a `Cache` built with an attached `CacheLoader`. (...) The canonical way to query a `LoadingCache` is with the method `get(K)`. This will **either return an already cached value, or else use the cache's CacheLoader to atomically load a new value** into the cache.

Moreover:

> Because `CacheLoader` might throw an `Exception`, `LoadingCache.get(K)` throws `ExecutionException`. (...) You can also choose to use `getUnchecked(K)`, which wraps all exceptions in `UncheckedExecutionException`, but this may lead to surprising behavior if the underlying `CacheLoader` would normally throw checked exceptions.